# No email and housekeep when add remove-item

Tags: windows, powershell

Scripting is about if not able find path, then will send email and output to FileA. If able to find path and delete any log older than 30 days and output to FileA. If add Get-ChildItem that row, the script below will not do any housekeep + output to txt file and send email to user. If i revoke the Get-ChildItem that row, it will send email to user.

What I want:

1. Send email if cannot find path and output to FileA. If able to find path, housekeep log older than 30 days and output to FileA
2. Send email if cannot find path and output to FileB. If able to find path, housekeep log older than 30 days and output to FileB

####Declare file path to be housekeep
$housekeepLog = "D:\logs-Copy*"       << valid path
$housekeepLog2 = "D:\logs-Copy2*"     << not valid path, purposely to test send email

```
####Housekeep any log older than 30days
>when add 2 sentence below, cannot send out email and no output to text file. when remove this, will send email and output to text file.
Get-ChildItem –Path $housekeepLog -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} | Remove-Item 
Get-ChildItem –Path $housekeepLog2 -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} | Remove-Item


####Output file
$outputHousekeep = "D:\Housekeep.txt"
$outputHousekeep2 = "D:\Housekeep2.txt"

$timestampDateTime = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')


#### housekeepLog
$EmailSplatHousekeep = @{
To =  "myemail@mydomain.com"
CC =  "myemail@mydomain.com"
SmtpServer = "smptserver@mydomain.com" 
From = "noreply@mydomain.com"
Priority = "High"
BodyAsHtml = $true
Subject = "Folder of Log File Does't Exist"
}

if (!(Test-Path $housekeepLog))
{
    $EmailSplatHousekeep.body = 
    "
    1. do something
    "
    
    Send-MailMessage @EmailSplatHousekeep
    Write-Output "$timestampDateTime The folder $housekeepLog doesn't exist! Check the folder path!" | Out-file $outputHousekeep  -Append
}
else
{
    ####Input to outputfile
    Write-Output "$timestampDateTime Done housekeeping in $housekeepLog ." | Out-file $outputHousekeep  -Append
}

#### housekeepLog2
$EmailSplatHousekeep2 = @{
To =  "myemail@mydomain.com"
CC =  "myemail@mydomain.com"
SmtpServer = "smptserver@mydomain.com" 
From = "noreply@mydomain.com"
Priority = "High"
BodyAsHtml = $true
Subject = "Folder of Log File Does't Exist"
}

if (!(Test-Path $housekeepLog2))
{
    $EmailSplatHousekeep2.body = 
    "
    1. do something
    "
    
    Send-MailMessage @EmailSplatHousekeep2
    Write-Output "$timestampDateTime The folder $housekeepLog2 doesn't exist! Check the folder path!" | Out-file $outputHousekeep2  -Append
}
else
{
    ####Input to outputfile
    Write-Output "$timestampDateTime Done housekeeping in $housekeepLog2 ." | Out-file $outputHousekeep2  -Append
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you can combine this using an array of `housekeepingLog` paths and loop over them, which will save you a lot of repeating code.

The main problem with your code is that you remove the old logs straight away and therefore afterwards there is no way of telling what you have removed..

Something like this:

```
# Declare file path to be housekeep 
# first path in array is valid, second path is not
$housekeepLog = "D:\logs-Copy", "D:\logs-Copy2"
$timestamp    = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')

foreach ($path in $housekeepLog) {
    if (Test-Path $path -PathType Container) {
        # the path exists, get logfiles older than 30 days
        $refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).Date  # set time to 00:00:00 (aka midnight)
        # assuming the log files have the '.txt' extension.. If different, then change that in the Filter
        $oldLogs = Get-ChildItem –Path $path -Filter '*.txt' -File -Recurse |    
                   Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate}
        if ($oldLogs) {
            # save the full path and names of the old logfiles that are being deleted
            $currentFolder = Split-Path -Path $path -Leaf
            $outputFile    = "D:\Housekeep-$currentFolder.txt"
            Add-Content -Path $outputFile -Value $oldLogs.FullName
            Add-Content -Path $outputFile -Value "$timestamp - Done housekeeping in $path.`r`n"

            # remove the old log files
            $oldLogs | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "No log files older than 30 days found in $path"
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "The folder '$path' does not exist.`r`nCheck the folder path!"
        # the path is not found, send email
        $emailProperties = @{
            To         = "myemail@mydomain.com"
            CC         = "myemail@mydomain.com"
            Subject    = "Folder '$path' does not exist"
            SmtpServer = "smptserver@mydomain.com"
            From       = "noreply@mydomain.com"
            Priority   = "High"
            Body       = "The folder $path does not exist.<br>Check the folder path!"
            BodyAsHtml = $true
        }
        Send-MailMessage @emailProperties
    }
}
```